# Is it safe to change a Custom Post Type from "hierarchical:false" to "hierarchical:true"?

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

We have a Custom Post Type with contents on it, that always had its `hierarchical` setting set to `false`, and we'd like to change it so some new contents are organized as child of the old contents.

I don't know very well the intricacies behind the Custom Post Types, so I wondered if setting the `hierarchical` to `true`, would damage in some way the old contents?

I understand that SEO wouldn't be affected, because only new contents would acquire the new URL hierarchy, right?

Thanks for any hint,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front end should be fine and would not affect anything, just make sure to flush your permalinks.

Your real issue will be in the back end. If you have a lot of posts, or planning to have plenty (*hundreds ++*), making a post type hierarchical would be fatal. Because Wordpress builds trees for hierarchical post types in the back end, which is really expensive operations, you will get a fatal error due to memory exhausted or maximum time exceeded if you have hundreds or thousands of posts.

### EDIT

With the amount of posts that you are planning, you should be fine, although you will find that your back end page for that post type will load much slower. If you can live with that, well, yes, then you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We plan to have only one sub-level below the parents, and not many sub-items: like 15 to 20 cases of 5 sub-items each.